# HTML - how to make an entire DIV a hyperlink?

Tags: html, xhtml, hyperlink

How do I make an entire `DIV` a clickable hyperlink. Meaning, I essentially want to do:

```
<div class="myclass" href="example.com">
    <div>...</div>
    <table><tr>..</tr></table>
    ....
</div>
```

And whenever someone mouse hovers of the myclass `DIV`, I want the entire `DIV` it to be a clickable hyperlink.

Comment: You can put any content you want inside an `<a>` element.  There's no reason to use a `<div>` here.

Comment: `<div />` is an element which is supposed to contain other elements or information, 

`<a />` is element, which makes 'actions' on those information (navigation, pagination, etc..)

so why do you want to have a whole clickable div when you have `<a />`?

Comment: @SLacks: That is not true. `<a>` is an inline level element capable of holding only inline level elements. Which means that having `<div>` and/or `<table>` has children of an `<a>` is not valid XHTML. To workaround this limitation, use inline elements and CSS to display them as block level elements. See http://www.cs.sfu.ca/CC/165/common/ref/wdgxhtml10/inline.html for a list of inline elements.

Comment: well i think that when developing website applications and you really want to have valid code, rather use a less strict validation model like html 4.01 trans. or html 5, which accepts block elements insde let's say `<a />`... also imagine google bot, do you think it can crawl your pages just from a  `window.open('example.com', 'wnd');` ? This is how flames start... :-D

Comment: https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Techniques/failures/F59

Answer (score 180, accepted):

You can add the onclick for JavaScript into the div.

```
<div onclick="location.href='newurl.html';">&nbsp;</div>
```

EDIT: for new window

```
<div onclick="window.open('newurl.html','mywindow');" style="cursor: pointer;">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: When I do that, my mouse cursor doesn't change to a hand like it does when hovering over a link. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You would need to use window.open. There are many canned scripts that perform this action. http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml

Comment: if you modified the move to be, cursor:pointer - that works

Comment: Use `cursor: pointer` instead of `cursor: hand`.

Comment: That wouldn't be very good for SEO. Search engines wouldn't see the hyperlink if it was coded in JavaScript.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Techniques/failures/F59

Comment: @danielnixon: That's a fantastic resource and something any developer should consider when creating a user interface of any kind through the web. This question didn't have any such considerations and asked only "how to do it". Perhaps your comment is best suited at the question level because it is certainly relevant.

Answer (score 26):

You can put an `<a>` element inside the `<div>` and set it to `display: block` and `height: 100%`.

Comment: That won't work because I have a lot of content inside the DIV. I'll update my original post to make it more descriptive

Comment: @Teddy: Adding `position:relative;` to the `div` and then `position: absolute; height: 100%;` to the `a` as well... should make the entire area of the `div` is active.

Comment: You can put all of that content inside the `<a>`.

Comment: Demo: http://jsbin.com/adoka/

Comment: That is not true. `<a>` is an inline level element capable of holding only inline level elements. Which means that having `<div>` and/or `<table>` has children of an `<a>` is not valid XHTML. To workaround this limitation, use inline elements and CSS to display them as block level elements. See http://www.cs.sfu.ca/CC/165/common/ref/wdgxhtml10/inline.html for a list of inline elements.

Comment: FYI: If the `<a>` were made an overlay, as prodigitalson suggested, then none of the elements "behind" the `<a>` would be selectable.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me with `<td><a...></a></td>`

Comment: works like a charm if you cannot use javascript solution presented above!

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 18):

You just need to specify the cursor as a pointer, not a hand, as pointer is now the standard, so, here's the example page code:

```
<div onclick="location.href='portable-display-stands.html';" id="smallbox">The content of the div here</div>
```

and the example CSS:

```
#smallbox {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

So the div is now a clickable element using 'onclick' and you've faked the hand cursor with the CSS...job done, works for me!

Comment: https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Techniques/failures/F59

Answer (score 15):

*This is a late answer, but this question appears highly on search results so it's worth answering properly.*

Basically, you shouldn't be trying to make a div clickable, but rather make an anchor div-like by giving the `<a>` tag a `display: block` CSS attribute.

That way, your HTML remains semantically valid and you can inherit the typical browser behaviours for hyperlinks. It also works even if javascript is disabled / js resources don't load.

Answer (score 7):

Add an `onclick` to your `DIV` tag.

http://webdevjunk.com/coding/javascript/3/use-onclick-to-make-entire-div-or-other-html-object-into-a-link/

Comment: Also, set the div's cursor style to pointer so the whole thing gets the finger.

Comment: The sample at the link shows that setting as well.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Techniques/failures/F59

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you just do this

```
<a href="yoururl.html"><div>...</div></a>
```

That should work fine and will prompt the "clickable item" cursor change, which the aforementioned solution will not do.

Comment: This is valid HTML5 DOCTYPE only ... Wont validate if you're using HTML4 or XHTML

Comment: You need to make the anchor a block for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

alternative would be javascript and forwarding via the onclick event

```
<div onclick="window.location.href='somewhere...';">...</div>
```

Comment: When I do that, my mouse cursor doesn't change to a hand like it does when hovering over a link. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: onclick actually does not make it a link but just clickable.
You could use the css cursor attribute to change it likewise.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Techniques/failures/F59